# Should OAuth2 DCR (RFC 7591) be used by the client itself to register with Authorization server?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to understand OAuth2 DCR (RFC 7591) and DCM (RFC 7592).
Should OAuth2 DCR (RFC 7591) be used by the client itself to register with Authorization server? Or can it be used by another registrar to register a client with authorization server?
For example, when a user first installs my mobile app, the app first connects to a backend service, which in turn registers the mobile app with my authorization server using DCR. Once the backend service gets registration details (such as clientid/secret etc) from authorization server, it passes this details to the mobile app. Mobile app now can request tokens directly from authorization server using clientid/secret it has received this way. The advantage of this approach is the registrar app also knows about this registration (say user A is using the application on mobile device m1), and can provide feature such as remove device, update device using the DCM (RFC 7592).

Is this the correct approach to take for this scenario?

Also, the DCM (RFC 7592) mention the use of Registration Access token, to use the Client configuration endpoint to get/update/delete the client configuration. In the scenario I mention above, it seems that Registration Access token should be stored at the registrar app. Again, is this correct the correct way to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Approach looks fine. registration token should be stored in the registrar server only as you are providing the feature of updating, deleting through registrar server only. Also, exposing the registration token to client app which resides on end user app can result in security vulnerabilities.